# Resetting board in pygame giving an Attribute Error

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a chess game and I was trying to implement a reset function. I have two files: my main game file and my chess engine. Here they are:

Main file (ChessMate.py):

```
import ChessEngine

WIDTH = HEIGHT = 512
DIMENSION = 8
SQ_SIZE = HEIGHT//DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 15
IMAGES = {}


def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK',
              'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(
            p.image.load('Chess/Images/' + piece + '.png'), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
    validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
    moveMade = False
    animate = False
    loadImages()
    running = True
    sqSelected = ()
    playerClicks = []
    gameOver = False
    while running:
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif e.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if not gameOver:
                    location = p.mouse.get_pos()
                    col = location[0]//SQ_SIZE
                    row = location[1]//SQ_SIZE
                    if sqSelected == (row, col):
                        sqSelected = ()
                        playerClicks = []
                    else:
                        sqSelected = (row, col)
                        playerClicks.append(sqSelected)
                    if len(playerClicks) == 2:
                        move = ChessEngine.Move(
                            playerClicks[0], playerClicks[1], gs.board)
                        print(move.getChessNotation())
                        for i in range(len(validMoves)):
                            if move == validMoves[i]:
                                gs.makeMove(validMoves[i])
                                moveMade = True
                                animate = True
                                sqSelected = ()
                                playerClicks = []
                        if not moveMade:
                            playerClicks = [sqSelected]
            elif e.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == p.K_z:
                    gs.undoMove()
                    moveMade = True
                    animate = False
                if e.key == p.K_r:
                    gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
                    validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
                    sqSelected = ()
                    playerClicks = ()
                    moveMade = False
                    animate = False

        if moveMade:
            if animate:
                animateMove(gs.moveLog[-1], screen, gs.board, clock)
            validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
            moveMade = False
            animate = False

        drawGameState(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected)

        if gs.checkMate:
            gameOver = True
            if gs.whitetoMove:
                drawText(screen, ' Black wins by Checkmate')
            else:
                drawText(screen, ' White wins by Checkmate')
        elif gs.staleMate:
            gameOver = True
            drawText(screen, 'Stalemate')

        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
        p.display.flip()


def highlightSquares(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected):
    if sqSelected != ():
        r, c = sqSelected
        if gs.board[r][c][0] == ('w' if gs.whitetoMove else 'b'):
            s = p.Surface((SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
            s.set_alpha(100)
            s.fill(p.Color('blue'))
            screen.blit(s, (c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE))
            s.fill(p.Color('yellow'))
            for move in validMoves:
                if move.startRow == r and move.startCol == c:
                    screen.blit(s, (SQ_SIZE*move.endCol, SQ_SIZE*move.endRow))


def drawGameState(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected):
    drawBoard(screen)
    highlightSquares(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected)
    drawPieces(screen, gs.board)


def drawBoard(screen):
    global colors
    colors = [p.Color("white"), p.Color("gray")]
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            color = colors[((r+c) % 2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, color, p.Rect(
                c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def drawPieces(screen, board):
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            piece = board[r][c]
            if piece != "--":
                screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], p.Rect(
                    c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def animateMove(move, screen, board, clock):
    global colors
    dR = move.endRow - move.startRow
    dC = move.endCol - move.startCol
    framesPerSquare = 10
    frameCount = (abs(dR) + abs(dC)) * framesPerSquare
    for frame in range(frameCount + 1):
        p.event.pump()
        r, c = (move.startRow + dR * frame / frameCount,
                move.startCol + dC*frame / frameCount)
        drawBoard(screen)
        drawPieces(screen, board)
        color = colors[(move.endRow + move.endCol) % 2]
        endSquare = p.Rect(move.endCol*SQ_SIZE,
                           move.endRow*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE)
        p.draw.rect(screen, color, endSquare)
        if move.pieceCaptured != '--':
            screen.blit(IMAGES[move.pieceCaptured], endSquare)
        screen.blit(IMAGES[move.pieceMoved], p.Rect(
            c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
        p.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


def drawText(screen, text):
    font = p.font.SysFont("Helvetica", 32, True, False)
    textObject = font.render(text, 0, p.Color('Gray'))
    textLocation = p.Rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT).move(
        WIDTH/2 - textObject.get_width()/2, HEIGHT/2 - textObject.get_height()/2)
    screen.blit(textObject, textLocation)
    textObject = font.render(text, 0,  p.Color("Black"))
    screen.blit(textObject, textLocation.move(2, 2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the chess Engine (chessEngine.py):

```
class GameState():
    def __init__(self):
        # 8x8 2d board, each element has 2 characters.
        self.board = [
            ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bB", "bN", "bR"],
            ["bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp"],
            ["wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "wB", "wN", "wR"]]
        self.moveFunctions = {'p': self.getPawnMoves,
                              'R': self.getRookMoves, 'N': self.getKnightMoves, 'B': self.getBishopMoves, 'Q': self.getQueenMoves, 'K': self.getKingMoves}

        self.whitetoMove = True
        self.moveLog = []
        self.whiteKingLocation = (7, 4)
        self.blackKingLocation = (0, 4)
        self.checkMate = False
        self.staleMate = False
        self.enpassantPossible = ()
        self.currentCastlingRight = CastleRights(True, True, True, True)
        self.castleRightsLog = [CastleRights(
            self.currentCastlingRight.wks, self.currentCastlingRight.wqs, self.currentCastlingRight.bks, self.currentCastlingRight.bqs)]

    def makeMove(self, move):
        self.board[move.startRow][move.startCol] = "--"
        self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceMoved
        self.moveLog.append(move)
        self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove

        if move.pieceMoved == 'wK':
            self.whiteKingLocation = (move.endRow, move.endCol)
        elif move.pieceMoved == "bK":
            self.blackKingLocation = (move.endRow, move.endCol)

        if move.isPawnPromotion:
            self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceMoved[0] + 'Q'

        if move.isEnpassantMove:
            self.board[move.startRow][move.endCol] = '--'

        if move.pieceMoved[1] == 'p' and abs(move.startRow - move.endRow) == 2:
            self.enpassantPossible = (
                (move.startRow + move.endRow)//2, move.startCol)
        else:
            self.enpassantPossible = ()

        if move.isCastleMove:
            if move.endCol - move.startCol == 2:
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol -
                                        1] = self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol+1]
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol+1] = '--'
            else:
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol +
                                        1] = self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol-2]
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol-2] = '--'

        self.updateCastleRights(move)
        self.castleRightsLog.append(CastleRights(
            self.currentCastlingRight.wks, self.currentCastlingRight.wqs, self.currentCastlingRight.bks, self.currentCastlingRight.bqs))

    def undoMove(self):
        if len(self.moveLog) != 0:
            move = self.moveLog.pop()
            self.board[move.startRow][move.startCol] = move.pieceMoved
            self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceCaptured
            self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove

        if move.pieceMoved == 'wK':
            self.whiteKingLocation = (move.startRow, move.startCol)
        elif move.pieceMoved == "bK":
            self.blackKingLocation = (move.startRow, move.startCol)

        if move.isEnpassantMove:
            self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = '--'
            self.board[move.startRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceCaptured
            self.enpassantPossible = (move.endRow, move.endCol)

        if move.pieceMoved[1] == 'p' and abs(move.startRow - move.endRow) == 2:
            self.enpassantPossible = ()

        self.castleRightsLog.pop()
        newRights = self.castleRightsLog[-1]
        self.currentCastlingRight = CastleRights(
            newRights.wks, newRights.bks, newRights.wqs, newRights.bqs)

        if move.isCastleMove:
            if move.endCol - move.startCol == 2:
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol +
                                        1] = self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol-1]
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol-1] = '--'
            else:
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol -
                                        2] = self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol+1]
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol+1] = '--'

    def updateCastleRights(self, move):
        if move.pieceMoved == 'wK':
            self.currentCastlingRight.wks = False
            self.currentCastlingRight.wqs = False
        elif move.pieceMoved == 'bK':
            self.currentCastlingRight.bks = False
            self.currentCastlingRight.bqs = False
        elif move.pieceMoved == 'wR':
            if move.startRow == 7:
                if move.startCol == 0:
                    self.currentCastlingRight.wqs = False
                elif move.startCol == 7:
                    self.currentCastlingRight.wks = False
        elif move.pieceMoved == 'bR':
            if move.startRow == 0:
                if move.startCol == 0:
                    self.currentCastlingRight.bqs = False
                elif move.startCol == 7:
                    self.currentCastlingRight.bks = False

    def getValidMoves(self):
        tempEnpassantPossible = self.enpassantPossible
        tempCastleRights = CastleRights(self.currentCastlingRight.wks, self.currentCastlingRight.bks,
                                        self.currentCastlingRight.wqs, self.currentCastlingRight.bqs)
        moves = self.getAllPossibleMoves()
        if self.whitetoMove:
            self.getCastleMoves(
                self.whiteKingLocation[0], self.whiteKingLocation[1], moves)
        else:
            self.getCastleMoves(
                self.blackKingLocation[0], self.blackKingLocation[1], moves)
        for i in range(len(moves)-1, -1, -1):
            self.makeMove(moves[i])
            self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove
            if self.inCheck():
                moves.remove(moves[i])
            self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove
            self.undoMove()
        if len(moves) == 0:
            if self.inCheck():
                self.checkMate = True
            else:
                self.staleMate = True
        else:
            self.checkMate = False
            self.staleMate = False
        self.enpassantPossible = tempEnpassantPossible
        self.currentCastlingRight = tempCastleRights
        return moves

    def inCheck(self):
        if self.whitetoMove:
            return self.squareUnderAttack(self.whiteKingLocation[0], self.whiteKingLocation[1])
        else:
            return self.squareUnderAttack(self.blackKingLocation[0], self.blackKingLocation[1])

    def squareUnderAttack(self, r, c):
        self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove
        oppMoves = self.getAllPossibleMoves()
        self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove
        for move in oppMoves:
            if move.endRow == r and move.endCol == c:
                return True
        return False

    def getAllPossibleMoves(self):
        moves = []
        for r in range(len(self.board)):
            for c in range(len(self.board[r])):
                turn = self.board[r][c][0]
                if (turn == 'w' and self.whitetoMove) or (turn == 'b' and not self.whitetoMove):
                    piece = self.board[r][c][1]
                    self.moveFunctions[piece](r, c, moves)
        return moves

    def getPawnMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        if self.whitetoMove:
            if self.board[r-1][c] == "--":
                moves.append(Move((r, c), (r-1, c), self.board))
                if r == 6 and self.board[r-2][c] == "--":
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r-2, c), self.board))
            if c - 1 >= 0:
                if self.board[r-1][c-1][0] == 'b':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r-1, c-1), self.board))
                elif (r - 1, c - 1) == self.enpassantPossible:
                    moves.append(
                        Move((r, c), (r-1, c-1), self.board, enpassantPossible=True))

            if c + 1 <= 7:
                if self.board[r-1][c+1][0] == 'b':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r-1, c+1), self.board))
                elif (r - 1, c + 1) == self.enpassantPossible:
                    moves.append(
                        Move((r, c), (r-1, c+1), self.board, enpassantPossible=True))

        else:
            if self.board[r+1][c] == "--":
                moves.append(Move((r, c), (r+1, c), self.board))
                if r == 1 and self.board[r+2][c] == '--':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r+2, c), self.board))

            if c-1 >= 0:
                if self.board[r+1][c-1][0] == 'w':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r+1, c-1), self.board))
                elif (r + 1, c - 1) == self.enpassantPossible:
                    moves.append(
                        Move((r, c), (r+1, c-1), self.board, enpassantPossible=True))

            if c+1 <= 7:
                if self.board[r+1][c+1][0] == 'w':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r+1, c+1), self.board))
                elif (r + 1, c + 1) == self.enpassantPossible:
                    moves.append(
                        Move((r, c), (r+1, c+1), self.board, enpassantPossible=True))

    def getRookMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        directions = ((-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1))
        enemyColor = "b" if self.whitetoMove else "w"
        for d in directions:
            for i in range(1, 8):
                endRow = r + d[0] * i
                endCol = c + d[1] * i
                if 0 <= endRow < 8 and 0 <= endCol < 8:
                    endPiece = self.board[endRow][endCol]
                    if endPiece == "--":
                        moves.append(
                            Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))
                    elif endPiece[0] == enemyColor:
                        moves.append(
                            Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))
                        break
                    else:
                        break
                else:
                    break

    def getKnightMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        knightMoves = ((-2, -1), (-2, 1), (-1, -2), (-1, 2),
                       (1, -2), (1, 2), (2, -1), (2, 1))
        allyColor = "w" if self.whitetoMove else "b"
        for m in knightMoves:
            endRow = r + m[0]
            endCol = c + m[1]
            if 0 <= endRow < 8 and 0 <= endCol < 8:
                endPiece = self.board[endRow][endCol]
                if endPiece[0] != allyColor:
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))

    def getBishopMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        directions = ((-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1))
        enemyColor = "b" if self.whitetoMove else "w"
        for d in directions:
            for i in range(1, 8):
                endRow = r + d[0] * i
                endCol = c + d[1] * i
                if 0 <= endRow < 8 and 0 <= endCol < 8:
                    endPiece = self.board[endRow][endCol]
                    if endPiece == "--":
                        moves.append(
                            Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))
                    elif endPiece[0] == enemyColor:
                        moves.append(
                            Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))
                        break
                    else:
                        break
                else:
                    break

    def getQueenMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        self.getRookMoves(r, c, moves)
        self.getBishopMoves(r, c, moves)

    def getKingMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        kingMoves = ((-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1),
                     (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1))
        allyColor = "w" if self.whitetoMove else "b"
        for i in range(8):
            endRow = r + kingMoves[i][0]
            endCol = c + kingMoves[i][1]
            if 0 <= endRow < 8 and 0 <= endCol < 8:
                endPiece = self.board[endRow][endCol]
                if endPiece[0] != allyColor:
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))

    def getCastleMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        if self.squareUnderAttack(r, c):
            return
        if (self.whitetoMove and self.currentCastlingRight.wks) or (not self.whitetoMove and self.currentCastlingRight.bks):
            self.getKingsideCastleMoves(r, c, moves)
        if (self.whitetoMove and self.currentCastlingRight.wqs) or (not self.whitetoMove and self.currentCastlingRight.bqs):
            self.getQueensideCastleMoves(r, c, moves)

    def getKingsideCastleMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        if self.board[r][c+1] == '--' and self.board[r][c+2] == '--':
            if not self.squareUnderAttack(r, c+1) and not self.squareUnderAttack(r, c+2):
                moves.append(
                    Move((r, c), (r, c+2), self.board, isCastleMove=True))

    def getQueensideCastleMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        if self.board[r][c-1] == '--' and self.board[r][c-2] == '--' and self.board[r][c-3] == '--':
            if not self.squareUnderAttack(r, c-1) and not self.squareUnderAttack(r, c-2):
                moves.append(
                    Move((r, c), (r, c-2), self.board, isCastleMove=True))


class CastleRights():
    def __init__(self, wks, bks, wqs, bqs):
        self.wks = wks
        self.bks = bks
        self.wqs = wqs
        self.bqs = bqs


class Move():
    ranksToRows = {"1": 7, "2": 6, "3": 5,
                   "4": 4, "5": 3, "6": 2, "7": 1, "8": 0}
    rowsToRanks = {v: k for k, v in ranksToRows.items()}
    filesToCols = {"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2,
                   "d": 3, "e": 4, "f": 5, "g": 6, "h": 7}
    colsToFiles = {v: k for k, v in filesToCols.items()}

    def __init__(self, startSq, endSq, board, enpassantPossible=False, isCastleMove=False):
        self.startRow = startSq[0]
        self.startCol = startSq[1]
        self.endRow = endSq[0]
        self.endCol = endSq[1]
        self.pieceMoved = board[self.startRow][self.startCol]
        self.pieceCaptured = board[self.endRow][self.endCol]

        self.isPawnPromotion = (self.pieceMoved == 'wp' and self.endRow == 0) or (
            self.pieceMoved == 'bp' and self.endRow == 7)

        self.isEnpassantMove = enpassantPossible
        if self.isEnpassantMove:
            self.pieceCaptured = 'wp' if self.pieceMoved == 'bp' else 'bp'

        self.isCastleMove = isCastleMove

        self.moveID = self.startRow * 1000 + \
            self.startCol*100 + self.endRow*10 + self.endCol

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Move):
            return self.moveID == other.moveID
        return False

    def getChessNotation(self):
        return self.getRankFile(self.startRow, self.startCol) + self.getRankFile(self.endRow, self.endCol)

    def getRankFile(self, r, c):
        return self.colsToFiles[c] + self.rowsToRanks[r]
```

The game resets, however when I try and make my next move, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/---/Documents/Python/AI/Chess/Chess/ChessMate.py", line 171, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/---/Documents/Python/AI/Chess/Chess/ChessMate.py", line 47, in main
    playerClicks.append(sqSelected)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error because **playerClicks** is a list.
The only reason I can see is the fact that **sqSelected** is a tuple, however I don't see why this would affect anything.

Please Help...

Comment: "I am not sure why I am getting this error because playerClicks is a list." The computer is telling you it's a tuple, at this point in time, and the computer cannot be wrong about this. This is way too much code to expect someone on Stack Overflow to scan through for you, but you need to check everywhere that `playerClicks` gets a new value.

Comment: (Hint: try *searching* your code for `playerClicks = ()`.)

Comment: ... change `playerClicks = ()` to `playerClicks = []` in the application loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks but now I'm not able to move when I do it. This time, however, there is no error...  Any suggestions to why this might be happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `playerClicks` from a tuple to a list in the application loop

<s>`playerClicks = ()`</s>

```py
playerClicks = []
```